# Not being able to edit NSTextField on NSPopover even though Editable behavior is set

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nspopover

I have an application, which open popover with `NSTextField`. The text field is not editable. Behavior for text field is set to `Editable`. I still can paste and copy text to this field but i can't edit it.

Anyone knows, what can be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTextField not active in NSPopOver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010180/nstextfield-not-active-in-nspopover)

Answer (score 41):

**Not sure if you still need the answer, but there may be some others still looking. I found a solution on apple developer forums. Quoting the original author:**

The main problem is the way keyboard events works. Although the NSTextField (and all its superviews) receives keyboard events, it doesn't make any action. That happens because the view where the popover is atached, is in a window which can't become a key window. You can't access that window in any way, at least I couldn't. So the solution is override the method canBecomeKeyWindow for every NSWindow in our application using a category.

```
NSWindow+canBecomeKeyWindow.h
@interface NSWindow (canBecomeKeyWindow)

@end

NSWindow+canBecomeKeyWindow.m
@implementation NSWindow (canBecomeKeyWindow)

//This is to fix a bug with 10.7 where an NSPopover with a text field cannot be edited if its parent window won't become key
//The pragma statements disable the corresponding warning for overriding an already-implemented method
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

That makes the popover fully resposive. If you need another window which must respond NO to canBecomeKeyWindow, you can always make a subclass.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly how to do this?

Comment: When you add files to a project you can choose to add an "Objective-C category". That's what he did naming it "canBecomeKeyWindow". Copy paste what he posted onto your code and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I would +1 a thousand times if I could! :)

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this for a while as well, until I realized it was a bug.

However, instead of relying on an isActive state of a NSStatusItem view, I find it much more reliable to use the isShown property of the NSPopover you have implemented.

In my code, I have a NSPopover in a NSViewController:

```
  - (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
    {
        if([self class]==NSClassFromString(@"NSStatusBarWindow"))
        {
            NSPopover *mainPopover = [[((AppDelegate*)[NSApp delegate]) mainViewController] mainPopover];
            if(![mainPopover isShown])
                return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Balazs Toth's answer works, but if you're attaching the popover to NSStatusItem.view the status item becomes unresponsive - requiring two clicks to focus.

Comment: the_snitch: on which view should you override this selector?  overriding it on the NSStatusItem.view (which is a custom view i've written) does not work.  the selector never gets fired.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: https://github.com/aschuch/AXStatusItemPopup/pull/7/files#diff-59deb1d5472a04ad5e32e8fa6725e973R154 make this changes and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

What i found when working with this solution is that when **NSStatusItem** becomes unresponsive, you can easily override this behavior like this

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    if([self class]==NSClassFromString(@"NSStatusBarWindow")) {
        CBStatusBarView* view = [((CBAppDelegate*)[NSApp delegate]) statusItemView];
        if(![view isActive]) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You will check for the class of the window, if it matches the **NSStatusBarWindow** we can then check somehow if the **NSStatusItem** is active. If it is, that means we have to return YES, because this way the **NSPopover** from **NSStatusItem** will have all keyboard events.

What I'm using for checking if the **NSStatusItem** was clicked (or is active) is that in my own custom view i have a bool value which changes when user clicks on the **NSStatusItem**, system automatically checks for *"canBecomeKeyWindow"* and when it does it will *return NO* and after user clicks on it (while it is returning the *NO*) it will change the bool value and *return YES* when system asks again (when **NSPopover** is being clicked for **NSTextField** editing).

***Sidenotes***:

- **CBStatusBarView** is my custom view for **NSStatusItem**
- **CBAppDelegate** is my App Delegate class

Comment: Had the same problem but works now with this workaround

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this, I am working in Swift.

At the time where you wish the field to allow text entry, I have used `myTextField.becomeFirstReponder()`

To opt out; just use `myTextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug.  That bug report is exactly what I was trying to do.  Even down to creating the status item and overriding mousdown.

I can confirm that Balazs Toth's answer works.  I just wonder if it might get in the way down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If someone gets it and the solution above didn't do the trick for him.
The problem in my app was in the `info` tab in the `targets` my application was set to

```
Application is background only = true
```

and shulde of been

```
 Application is agent = true
```

Spent an entire day on this thing.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Bug. http://openradar.appspot.com/9722231