# How do I make a Menubar Application with a NSPopover?

Tags: xcode, menu, popover

I have seen a lot of applications with a Menubar Item or applications with only a Menubar interface.

There are some tutorials and stuff on the internet showing you how to accomplish that. But the thing is, those do only have clickable index rows in them.

I would want to have a NSPopover appear when you click the Menubar Icon / Item. Anybody who knows how to make this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't know if it can be done with a standard status bar item. Using a custom view for the menulet it's relatively easy.

Create a status bar item with a custom view:

```
item = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:thickness];
view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:(NSRect){.size={thickness, thickness}}];
[item setView:view];
```

Your custom view needs to detect mouse clicks:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
   ...
}
```

And finally, at some point after detecting the mouse click, show/hide the popover.

```
if (/* menulet is active */) {
    [popover showRelativeToRect:/* menulet view frame */
                         ofView:/* menulet view */
                  preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
} else {
    [popover performClose:nil];
}
```

You need a [bit of NSWindow swizzling](https://github.com/djromero/PopoverMenulet/blob/master/PopoverMenulet/NSWindow%2BBugFix.m) to get text fields working inside the popover.

I've prepared a minimal **Xcode project** with these ideas and some glue: [PopoverMenulet](https://github.com/djromero/PopoverMenulet).

Comment: You, sir, are a saint. Thank you for the awesome answer.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice, this is how all answers should be.

Comment: Using this method, I can't get a text field to activate. It seems like it's inactive, like when a window with a text field is not the active window. Anyone know how to activate a text field in this case?

Comment: It's a known bug that textfields aren't active in this situation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214273/nstextfield-on-nspopover/7794324#7794324

Comment: Have you delete your XCode Project  ?

Comment: Opps, sorry. I just renamed my user in github. I forgot to update this link. It's correct now.

Comment: Thanks for your great solution. One question. When the popover is active, I would like it to dismiss when I click another window, switch application etc. Currently I have to click the *NSStatusItem* to dismiss it. How should this be implemented?

Comment: The only way I can think right now is implementing an event tap. A pass-trough monitor that receives every click and if it's not inside the popover dismiss it.

Comment: Thank djromero, It is awesome.