# Popover NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem, nspopover

I'm playing around with an idea and basically I want a NSStatusItem with a NSPopoverController. I read about all the problem people had but I just want to try it. Is there a clean way to do it by now? All the versions I've seen are at least 1 year old and suuuuper hacky.

This was my approach so far but if I click my app in the statusbar nothing happens...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];

    //[self.statusItem setView:view];
    [self.statusItem setTitle:@"Test"];
    [self.statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [self.statusItem setAction:@selector(activatePopover:)];

}


-(IBAction)activatePopover:(id)sender
{
    BOOL isEnabled = NO;

    if (isEnabled) {
        [self.popover showRelativeToRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 50) ofView:statusItem.view preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];

    } else {
        [self.popover close];
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get this running?

Thanks

Comment: `showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge` is never called because `isEnabled` is set to NO.

Comment: `2014-04-29 17:14:08.377 Aves[610:303] -[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:]: nil view provided. You must supply a view.`

Comment: I have defined `popover`as `@property (strong) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;`

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837439/how-do-i-make-a-menubar-application-with-a-nspopover/7906025#7906025

Answer (score 7):

This will not work without using a custom view on the status item. If you don't set a custom view, the `view` property will be empty (it only returns custom views, not whatever view `NSStatusItem` uses internally when you just use `setTitle`).

Unfortunately, as per Apple's docs, you'll need to provide your own view and handle clicks yourself if you want to use `NSPopover`.

I haven't seen a complete example that encompasses correct handling of this (the default implementation of status items does rather a lot which you will have to do all manually), and also fixes popover wonkynesses:

- `NSPopover`, by default, won't become the key window (some controls won't work), unless you overwrite `canBecomeKeyWindow` of NSPopover's window
- Correctly dismissing menus of other status items (you can call `popUpStatusItemMenu` with an empty menu to correctly focus your status item)
- Drawing the highlighted background with `drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect`
- Reacting to both left and right mouse clicks
- Using `NSRunningApplication.currentApplication.activateWithOptions` to make sure all windows of your status item become active (otherwise your popover will, erratically, not be the receiver of keyboard input)
- Dismissing the NSPopover with `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` (the built-in dismissal mechanism popovers come with doesn't work with status items)
- Removing the status item on termination with `NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar.removeStatusItem`

I hope to have a blog post about this out sometime soon (note: I'm using RubyMotion, not Objective-C), that explains all these issues and hopefully provides an easier base to create menulets. I'll update this comment if I write that post.

Comment: MY HOLY GOD!!! Why Objective C and OS X development are SOOOOO strong and hard to understand?

Comment: Calling [NSRunningApplication.currentApplication activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps]; after showRelativeToRect worked for me.

Comment: Your answer seems to contain some helpful hints—however, it would be great if your were able to provide a complete solution. I wasn’t able to implement everything / get it work.

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
-(void)initializeStatusBarItem
{
    self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];
    NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"image"];
//    [image setTemplate:YES];
    self.statusItem.button.image = image;
    self.statusItem.highlightMode = NO;
    self.statusItem.button.action = @selector(statusBarItemDidClick:);
}

- (void)statusBarItemDidClick:(NSStatusBarButton *)sender{
    MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.popoverView = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
    [self.popoverView setContentViewController:mainView];
    self.popoverView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 400);
    self.popoverView.behavior = NSPopoverBehaviorTransient;
    [self.popoverView showRelativeToRect:sender.bounds ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
}
```

Comment: Ever since a StatusItem received the `button` property, this example works. Make sure to NOT set the `menu` of the statusItem though, otherwise the action is not being called and the menu opens.

Comment: Unfortunately after trying and trying this does not work, i get 
-[NSStatusItem window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000023fc320