# NSTextField isn't active on NSPopover attached to NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, menu, popover, nsstatusbar

I have a NSStatusItem created like this:

```
statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[statusItem setTitle:@"DS"];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setAction:@selector(StatusClicked:)];
[statusItem setTarget:self];
```

I also have a popover with customview. On the view I have textfield: http://d.pr/i/CWbr

My popover is shown like this:

```
- (void)StatusClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
}
```

From a debuger I learned that `sender` here is an instance of `NSStatusBarButton` class.

The problem is that when the popover pops I can't type in textfield, it apears inactive: http://d.pr/i/q18U

The button is working though.

I think that problem is in the view I pass to `ofView:`. I tried to change it to a control on window like this:

```
 [self.popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:self.postText preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
```

And textfield became active (http://d.pr/i/DmTz) but I have no idea why this helps.

Why does my popover textfield becomes inactive when poped from menu?
Why button works?
How can I make textfield active?

P. S.
My app is `Application is agent (UIElement)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the question I thought this can be related to key windows. So I searched for this connection and found this question: [Not being able to edit NSTextField on NSPopover even though Editable behavior is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214273/nstextfield-on-nspopover)

This answered my question perfectly. It apears to be a bug.