# NSTableView in popover not selecting row on first click

Tags: swift, nstableview, popover, macos-sierra

My app presents multiple tables in a popover from the status bar. When the user clicks on a row, in any of the tables, nothing happens. On the second click, tableViewSelectionDidChange gets fired and the row is selected.
Any ideas on how to fix this?
I thought at first it was a focus issue, with the first click giving the popover focus. However, the popover also has buttons which activate on their first click.

Comment: Storyboard or xibs? How do you show the popover?

Comment: It is a status bar app - so you click on the icon on the status bar to show the popover below. I use the storyboard to design the popover contents.

Comment: Maybe presenting the viewcontroller as popover fixes the issue. And otherwase this (old) question seems to be the same problem: [NSTextField isn't active on NSPopover attached to NSStatusItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597665/nstextfield-isnt-active-on-nspopover-attached-to-nsstatusitem).

Comment: I do present the view controller as a popover. I don't think this is the same as the "old" question. In my case, it is not that the tableview stays inactive (with button ok). It is just inactive for the very first click, then ok for 2nd and further clicks. Thanks for you help though.