# PyobjC : NSTextField on NSPopover

Tags: python, nswindow, pyobjc, nspopover

I have the same problem mentioned here : [Not being able to edit NSTextField on NSPopover even though Editable behavior is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214273/nstextfield-on-nspopover). The solution seems to be to override the canBecomeKeyWindow of NSWindow. I am trying to do the same thing in PyObjC, but I am getting an error `Python signature doesn't match implied objective-C signature`.

In the following code, if I comment out canBecomeKeyWindow_(), then the app runs as expected, but I am not able to click and edit the textfields.

```
# from Cocoa import *
from AppKit import NSWindowController, NSApplication, NSApp, NSMaxYEdge, NSImage, NSStatusBar, NSMenu, NSMenuItem, NSVariableStatusItemLength, NSRect
from Cocoa import objc

from Foundation import NSUserNotification, NSUserNotificationCenter, NSObject
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import os
global popover


class TestApp(NSApplication):

    def finishLaunching(self):
        # Make statusbar item
        statusbar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
        self.statusitem = statusbar.statusItemWithLength_(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        self.icon = NSImage.alloc().initByReferencingFile_('app-icon.png')
        self.icon.setScalesWhenResized_(True)
        self.icon.setSize_((20, 20))
        self.statusitem.setImage_(self.icon)
        self.statusitem.setHighlightMode_(1)
                # make the menu
        self.menubarMenu = NSMenu.alloc().init()
        self.menuItem = NSMenuItem.alloc().initWithTitle_action_keyEquivalent_('Login', 'loginCallback:', '')
        self.menubarMenu.addItem_(self.menuItem)

        self.quit = NSMenuItem.alloc().initWithTitle_action_keyEquivalent_('Quit', 'terminate:', '')
        self.menubarMenu.addItem_(self.quit)

        # add menu to statusitem
        self.statusitem.setMenu_(self.menubarMenu)

    def loginCallback_(self, notification):
        # Initiate the contrller with a XIB
        viewController = SimpleXibDemoController.alloc().initWithWindowNibName_("Login")

        # Show the window
        viewController.showWindow_(viewController)
        rect = self.statusitem.valueForKey_('button').frame()
        viewController.popover.showRelativeToRect_ofView_preferredEdge_(rect, self.statusitem.valueForKey_('button'), NSMaxYEdge)


class SimpleXibDemoController(NSWindowController):
    popover = objc.IBOutlet()
    counterTextField = objc.IBOutlet()
    username_field = objc.IBOutlet()
    password_field = objc.IBOutlet()
    submit_button = objc.IBOutlet()

    def canBecomeKeyWindow_(self):
        return 1

    def windowDidLoad(self):
        NSWindowController.windowDidLoad(self)

    @objc.IBAction
    def submit_(self, sender):
        username = self.username_field.stringValue()
        password = self.password_field.stringValue()
        self.updateDisplay(username + ' ' + password)

    def updateDisplay(self, value):
        self.counterTextField.setStringValue_(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp.sharedApplication()
    icon = NSImage.alloc().initByReferencingFile_('app-icon.png')
    app.setApplicationIconImage_(icon)
    AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding an underscore where you shouldn't. The PyObjC bridge will translate it into a colon. Besides that, the corresponding Python boolean value should be `True`. Thus, the correct function would look like this:

```
def canBecomeKeyWindow(self):
    return True
```