# Cocoa: NSPopover in statusbar unresponsive

Tags: cocoa, statusbar, activation

An application has an NSPopover with some user inputs in the status bar and some windows. The windows work fine but when I open the popover in the status bar it opens inactive. I can see everything but it's all greyed out, like it's a background window. I've been trying everything I can find on activate, activateignoringotherapps, makekeyandorderfront, etc but none of these is having an effect. How can I shift the focus to the statusbar popover?

I also made a button in the window that showed the same popup to make sure it is working, when called from the window button it works perfectly from there. Then I click on the status bar, and it opens from there instead, but inactive.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTextField not active in NSPopOver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010180/nstextfield-not-active-in-nspopover)

Comment: Here's a hack that works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214273/nstextfield-on-nspopover/7794324#7794324

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem and haven't found a solution. Unfortunately, I believe this is a bug: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=1226415

Comment: Yeah, this seems to pretty much exactly describe my problem. Not much to do except wait for a patch. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like that's going to be a long wait. I'm having the same issues now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a framework called [SFBPopovers](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers) which provides similar functionality and works fine with the menu bar.

It might help with your issue.

Comment: Sorry I've taken so long. SFBPopovers is for mac 10.6 and as far as I know, I can't use it for Lion popovers.